# Create Unordered List from Object of arrays

Tags: javascript, list, for-loop, appendchild, createelement

I want to create an unordered list using vanilla JS to create a list from an array of objects. Not sure how to do that.

This is my current code:

```js
let myObj = [
  {name: "Harry Potter", author: "JK Rowling"},
  {name: "Hunger Games", author: "Suzanne Collins"},
  {name: "Lord of the Rings", author: "J. R. R. Tolkien"},
  {name: "Game of Thrones", author: "George R.R. Martin"},
  {name: "Percy Jackson", author: "Rick Riordan"},
];

console.log(myObj);

let myUL = document.createElement("UL");
myUL.setAttribute("id", "myUL");
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myUL);
for (const item of myObj) {
   document
   .getElementById("myUL")
   .appendChild(document.createElement("LI"));
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Not sure how to make my list look like:

- **JK Rowling**: Harry Potter
- **Suzanne Collins**: Hunger Games
- **J. R. R. Tolkien**: Lord of the Rings
- **George R.R. Martin**: Game of Thrones
- **Rick Riordan**: Percy Jackson

Using vanilla JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create a [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) tag in which you place `item.author`.

Then make a new [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) for the `item.name` using [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)

Then [append the textNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to the `li` and append that to the `ul`:

```js
const myObj = [
  {name: "Harry Potter", author: "JK Rowling"},
  {name: "Hunger Games", author: "Suzanne Collins"},
  {name: "Lord of the Rings", author: "J. R. R. Tolkien"},
  {name: "Game of Thrones", author: "George R.R. Martin"},
  {name: "Percy Jackson", author: "Rick Riordan"},
];

const myUL = document.createElement("UL");
myUL.setAttribute("id", "myUL");

const ul = document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myUL);

for (const item of myObj) {
    let author = document.createElement("strong");
    author. textContent = item.author + ': ';
    
    let li = document.createElement("li");    
    li.appendChild(author);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.name))
    
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To create your desired unordered list update the js as follows:

```
let myObj = [
  { name: "Harry Potter", author: "JK Rowling" },
  { name: "Hunger Games", author: "Suzanne Collins" },
  { name: "Lord of the Rings", author: "J. R. R. Tolkien" },
  { name: "Game of Thrones", author: "George R.R. Martin" },
  { name: "Percy Jackson", author: "Rick Riordan" },
];

let myUL = document.createElement("ul");
myUL.setAttribute("id", "myUL");

for (const item of myObj) {
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.textContent = `${item.author}: ${item.name}`;
  myUL.appendChild(listItem);
}

document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myUL);
```

In the modified code, created a `li` element then append it with `ul` element. If you want the name should be in bold you can use `<strong>` or `<b>`